# Reset a nice-select (jquery-nice-select) dropdown

Tags: jquery

How can I reset a dropdown created with JQuery Nice Select plugin ?
Nice Select JQuery Plugin: https://github.com/hernansartorio/jquery-nice-select

```
 <select name="married" class="nice-select">
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
 <option value="No">No</option>
 </select>


$('nice-select').niceSelect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Reset button click handling to reset the dropdown:

```
$('#reset_btn').on('click', function(e){
      $('.nice-select').val('');
      $('.nice-select').niceSelect('update'); 
});
```